# Modify URL with PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

How can I add parameters to URL whit PHP. In javascript I use something like

```
document.URL = "?param1=sth".
```

I have a list of article whit checkbox that have value equals article id (from the database) and when user check 1 checkbox I want to redirect him to `http://blablabla.com/edit?article_name=1(article id);`

```
$checkbox = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"article[]\" value=\"{$article["id"]}\"/>";
```

`$checkbox` are generate automatically depending on number of articles from the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']) AND isset($_POST['article'])){
    $articol = $_POST['article'];
    if (is_array($articol)) { 
            $contor = 0;
                foreach ($articol as $item) {
                    if(isset($item))
                        $contor ++;
                }
                if($contor == 1 ){
                **redirect user to edit.php?article_name=1;**
                }else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
                echo "alert(\"You can't edit more than 1 article!\")";
                echo "</script>";   
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Checkboxes imply choosing *zero or more* options, not *one*. That's what radio buttons are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) but you must make sure not to send any output before, or otherwise use output buffering. Also, calling `header` doesn't actually end the script, so it's a good thing to use an `exit` if you want to stop there.

```
header('Location: edit.php?article_name=1');
exit;
```